# Higher kernel_task CPU usage when playing audio through Thunderbolt Display

Tags: audio, performance, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

I noticed today a higher `kernel_task` CPU usage when playing audio through Thunderbolt Display from my Macbook Pro (early 2011) on OS X Yosemite. Although the CPU usage is not very high (15 - 20%), it certainly gets the fans spinning fast enough to get my attention. I would not expect this as a normal behaviour.

I've tried Spotify, iTunes and playing a YouTube video in Safari and got the same results. Here is an example when playing a song from iTunes through the internal speakers (I get the same values with headphones):

[image]

And here is the `kernel_task` usage when playing the same song through my Thunderbolt Display:

[image]

I have tried both SMC and PRAM resets, but to no avail. What could be causing this? Does anyone else experience this behaviour?

Comment: Same here, as soon as I select "Display Audio", kernel_task jumps to a steady 30%

Comment: I have this problem as well. I suspect it's related to the Thunderbolt display malfunctioning. Does anyone have a pair of MacBooks and a pair of Thunderbolt Displays the can use to test this?

Running 10.11.3 (15D21) a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013).